# What is the angle between two 4 dimensional vectors? $v_{1}=(-1,2,2,0),v_2=({2,-4,5,1})$

Tags: linear-algebra

$\cos(\theta)=\frac{uv}{\mid\mid u\mid\mid.\mid\mid v\mid\mid}$

As I use this formula I get that : $\cos(\theta)=\frac{uv}{\mid\mid u\mid\mid.\mid\mid v\mid\mid}=\frac{0}{(\sqrt9).(\sqrt45)}$

I think that my calculation is correct, but I don't know what is the angle of these vectors. Thank you for your help.

Comment: $\cos \theta =0\implies \theta =\pi/2$ when $0\le \theta\le \pi$.

Comment: omg , it was so trivial thank you...

Comment: You're welcome.  And no worry.  Sometimes it's easy to miss the easy things.